# Retrieve .aspx.vb files after publishing in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web

Is there is a way to get .aspx.vb files after executing publish operation in Visual studio (only .aspx files are available after publishing), since the backup of .aspx.vb files were deleted due to a system issue.

Comment: Shut down the computer *now*. Remove the disk drive that the files were on. Make a duplicate of that disk (look up how to do that). Use deleted file recovery software on the duplicate disk.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Andrew Morton, but other than there is no option to retrieve .aspx.vb files from Published files right?

Comment: First, remember that the more you do with the disk drive, the greater the chance that those files will be overwritten and hence lost forever. If you have a copy of the disk to examine, there is a chance that they'll be somewhere undeleted. What was the system issue? If it was only a small project, it may be easier to make it again, especially as you have the .aspx files. I assume it wasn't using version control, and no other backups were made, either of which would make it a simple task to get the data back.

Comment: To prevent it from happening again, always store your sources in some source control system. There are multiple options.

Comment: If you have the compiled dll (and possibly a pdb as well), then there are decompilers that recover 90% of the code.

Comment: Yes @Hans Kesting, there's dll as well as pdb